# Android Studio: How do I prevent this weird tabbing?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart

Sometimes when I fill out a widget's predefined inputs, Android Studio tabs over an extra 2 spaces (image examples below). Sometime it doesn't do this and instead just lines up the next item with the first. How do I prevent it from doing the extra tabbing and just line them all up with a single tabbing amount? For example, in the image below the `child` lines would start lined up with the `flex` lines above.

[image]

Comment: I think it depends on dart max line & end comma